# maven scope test with selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium

What is the difference when we use scope as test for some dependency in pom.xml file for a selenium project.
Example : Difference between

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
 <version>3.141.59</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

AND

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
 <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scope is `compile`.

This scope adds the dependency to the project at **compile-time** and will also be exported when you create a JAR with dependencies (or similar)

The `test` scope adds the dependency just for test sources(e.g. Unit tests/located in `src/test` in most cases). It can only be accessed from test sources and will **not** be export(except to a test JAR)

If you only need selenium in the test code of the project, I recommand using the `test` scope.

Comment: did u means this dependency cannot be used by classes in `src/main/java` or other folder of the project ??

Comment: Yes, only in `src/test/java`

Comment: And dependents of your project cannot use it too.

Answer (score 1):

### Dependency Scope in Maven

The [Dependency scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) is used to limit the transitivity of a dependency which also effects the classpath used for various build related tasks.

Currently the following 6 dependency scope are supported by [maven](/questions/tagged/maven):

- **`compile`**: `compile` scope is the default scope which is used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. These dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

  - Exmaple:

    ```
    <scope>compile</scope>
    ```
- **`provided`**: `provided` scope is almost similar to compile but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime.

  - Exmaple:

    ```
    <scope>provided</scope>
    ```
- **`runtime`**: `runtime` scope indicates that the dependency is not required at compile time but only for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

  - Exmaple:

    ```
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    ```
- **`test`**: `test` scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases. This scope is not transitive.

  - Exmaple:

    ```
    <scope>test</scope>
    ```
- **`system`**: `system` scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository.

  - Exmaple:

    ```
    <scope>system</scope>
    ```
- **`import`**: `import` scope is only supported on a dependency of type `pom` in the `<dependencyManagement>` section. It indicates the dependency to be replaced with the effective list of dependencies in the specified POM's  section.

  - Exmaple:

    ```
    <scope>import</scope>
    ```